# jquery ajax php json return not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Baffled... I have a file "api.php" shown below. This is called in the jquery ajax call. When I run it from the command line I get a response that appears correct (ie not empty). When I run it in the ajax call it appears to come back empty.  NOW... when I comment out the "if( $td < $lessthan )" and the two braces it all works correctly (i.e., the ajax success gets correct data.

Here is my "api.php" function:

```
    $basedir = "calls/";
    $now = time();

    $lessthan  = 20 * 60;
    $ret = array();
    $dir = opendir( $basedir );
    while(($currentFile = readdir($dir)) !== false)
    {
            if ( preg_match( '/(.*).txt/', $currentFile, $match) )
            {
                    $tt = @file_get_contents($basedir.$currentFile);
                    $td = ($now - @strtotime( $tt ));
                    if( $td < $lessthan )
                    {
                            $ret[] = $match[1];
                    }
            }
    }
    closedir($dir);

  echo json_encode(implode(',', $ret));
?>
```

Here is my jquery ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({                          
      url: 'api.php',                 
      data: "",                       
      dataType: "json",               
      type: "POST",                   
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {                                     
            console.log(data + ':' + previous + '  ' + textStatus );
            if( data != null && data != previous && data != "" )
            {                                                               previous = data;                
                    $('#other').hide(); //Set output element html
                    $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('fast').load('reload.php?q='+data).fadeIn("fast"); //Set output element html
            }

            if( (data == null || data == "" ) && previous != null )                {                                       
                    //$('#loaddiv').fadeOut('fast').html('No Active Calls').fadeIn("fast"); //Set output element html
                    $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('fast'); //Set output element html
                    $('#other').show();             
                    $('#other').fadeOut('fast').load('default.php').fadeIn("fast");
                    previous = null;                
            }                               
      },                              
      error: function(m) { alert('error'); } 
    });
```

Any ideas on why the commenting out the "if" statement in the api.php makes the whole thing work?  Or better yet, how can I leave the if statement in and for it to work.

Comment: remove @ before file_get_contest ant strtotime.. this block any error messages to come out..

Comment: ^ What he said. You're suppressing potentially helpful error messages.

Comment: I didn't have the "@" on there earlier -- removed now. No error messages. Still getting a success but no data.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** implode the array before json_encoding it!

Comment: Try to echo $tt after file_get_contest line and see if its some date format. And echo the strtotime result too..

Comment: Ok. I removed the implode but the console still shows an empty "data" variable. When I do "php api.php" from the command line it gives me ["130961319"] which is correct.

Comment: I have echoed the $tt and strtotime result and all those are correct. When I run it from the command line the echo statement gives me a correct response.

Comment: If you open api.php in the browser, what does it show? Are there any errors, or does console.log(data) just show up empty ?

Comment: Then the only problem may be that the difference between now time and the date is more then your limit.. and your IF skips it..

Comment: Huh, interesting adeneo. I ran the api.php in the browser and it gave me [] and when I run it at the prompt I get ["130961319"].  So why would they give me a different result? <scratching head>

Comment: Ah... weird.  So the file_get_contents does not pull info out of the file when in the browser.  I tried putting the full path to the file in there as well.  Why would file_get_contents not be reading the file?

Comment: Ok. I am now wondering if it is a permissions issue and it is not properly reading the file in the browser.  Thanks to adeneo for pointing out a great way to figure out my issues :-).